# How to use GLMM on factorial design, and resources for learning

Tags: glmm

If I have a 2^3 factorial design (2 levels, 3 factors) with 8 treatments that cover all 7 combinations + control for main effects and interaction effects, how do I model my data?

I want to use a GLMM. Do I use the factors as fixed effects and combine them in all various combinations across the entire dataset, or do I use treatment as fixed effects as the combinations are already determined within these?

```
model <- glmer(log(Response) ~ Factor1 + Factor2 + Factor3 + Facor1*Factor2 + Factor1*Factor3 + Factor2*Factor3 + Factor1*Factor2*Factor3 + (1|ID), family=poisson, data=mydata)

model <- glmer(log(Response) ~ Treatment +(1|ID), family=poisson, data=mydata)
```

I probably lack some basic understanding of how this works. I only have an introductory course in statistics, so if anyone has any good resources for GLM and GLMM for total noobs, I would really appreciate it. Or advice on what to read up on before going there. (I tried a book called "A beginners guide to GLM and GLMM with R" by Zuur et al, but even though a lot of the theory is in there, it is a bit tricky to find/look up as it is focused on the code).

---

First, thank you for the reply! It was clarifying.

And second, I’m using a glmm because I have repeat measures of eggs, pellets, hatching and development of the same ID. I also checked survival. My data is very skewed, and either categorical or non-negative integers, but a lot of zero’s! And hatching success is proportions ofcourse.

Since I aim to analyse survival and these repeat messurement data, would you reccomend reading up om joint modelling?

All comments are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first model would look like this:

`model <- glmer(log(Response) ~ Factor1*Factor2*Factor3 + (1|ID), family=poisson, data=mydata)`. This already includes all possible interactions and will also compute your main effects. So much simpler as you defined.

The second model is just the treatment and handles treat1 as beeing something completely different to treat2 and so on. So, you will not be able to find interactions between for example factor2 and factor3, which might be a pitty.

Something which is not explained by your question: Why a GLMM?. Obviously, you made a kind of repeated measurement, therefore the ID (You didn't mentioned it...).

Maybe you had a control and a 'probably effective other level than control' for every factor? That's the only way i can come to 7 treatments and a control. Therefore, i would go for the first model.

I could have been more precise, if more information was presented...

---

OK, these are different things. What do you mean with joint modelling? Multivariate like NMDS and others?

For the hatch I would recommend a binomial model. So either use cbind(succ,fail)~Factor1*Factor2..., familiy=binomial or be sure to give weights if you present a value of 0:1 (*100 = %)
For eggs a poisson might be ok. I wonder about the log(Response). I thought the family argument should handle your data in the right way. If not, there are some words which might help you to get further: zero
-inflation and overdispersion. But be aware of complete separation. However,  bit more precise description would be nice, but as this isn't a chit-chat forum, I think your original question is answered? If yes, please sign it as such. Thank you